# Running Internet Explorer with multiple tabs

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, powershell

How can i run IE using COM (powershell, C#, etc. - doesn't matter) or command-line args. with multiple tabs within one window.

For example:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("yahoo.com")
$ie.Navigate("google.com")
```

I want something like this, but insted of navigating within a single tab, open a second.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found: using [navigate flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx) we can manage this mechanism.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("yahoo.com")
$ie.Navigate("google.com", 0x0800)
```